# xargs - use EOF as delimeter

Tags: bash, xargs

How do I use the EOF as a delimeter in `xargs` such that the entire file is read?

E.g.

`cat foo.py | xargs -d EOF -I % python -c %`

I know there are other ways to get the above example to work, but I am interested in learning how to do the same with xargs.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since command-line arguments can never contain null bytes, your question essentially presupposes that your input does not contain null bytes. As a result, the simplest approach is to use null bytes as the delimiter, thereby guaranteeing that the entire input will be treated as a single item.

To do that, use the `--null` or `-0` option:

```
cat foo.py | xargs --null -I % python -c %
```

Or, more tersely:

```
xargs -0  python -c  < foo.py
```

That said, I can't picture what this is useful for. If you know that you will only ever have one input item, then why use `xargs` at all? Why not just write

```
python -c "$(< foo.py)"
```

?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the alternatives - I was just wondering if the same could be achieved using xargs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For `xargs` to read an entire file and turn it into a single argument would be a useless behavior.

What you're trying to do with:

```
# replace % with the contents of foo.py and pass as an argument
cat foo.py | xargs -d EOF -I % python -c %
```

can be done like this:

```
# pass contents of foo.py as a single argument
python -c "$(cat foo.py)"
```

but what is the point, since you can do:

```
python foo.py
```